# Dual-boot with or without Grub?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I need to install Ubuntu alongside my Windows system.

Since it is going to be on a separate disk, I am not sure if I should go for dual-boot with Grub or simply install Ubuntu totally separately on the other disk by physically disconnecting the Windows disk before installing Ubuntu. With this setup, I would choose the boot disk from BIOS instead of Grub.

I see people having problems with Grub when using separate disks. Would it perhaps be simpler choosing the disk from BIOS?

What could be the pros and cons of either choice?

Comment: When you choose from UEFI/BIOS you are choosing boot loader.  For LInux that most often is grub. Are you installing in UEFI or BIOS boot mode? Must be same boot mode as Windows. If Windows is UEFI with gpt partitioning you must install on second drive with UEFI/gpt. What version of Ubuntu. 22.04 & before use Ubiquity installer with this bug .  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/136379 Best to partition in advance using gpt partitioning include the ESP. https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator &

Comment: Im installing in UEFI. But is it a good idea in general? Some tell me it's not. Maybe virtual machine would be better?

Comment: Whether virtual or dual boot, you still use grub to boot. For UEFI you must have an ESP - efi system partition for boot files, whether grub, SystemD Boot or any other boot system. Note that grub is boot a boot manager (menu) and boot loader. You can use other boot managers like rEFInd, but still need a boot loader like grub or SystemD. Since grub is default with Ubuntu, you should use grub.

Comment: Thanks, guys, for the input. Since I needed Linux on this particular machine simply for running VS Code (because Bitdefender made Golang dead slow on native Windows) I decided to go for WSL. At the moment it looks like this works very well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Choose the default settings that are offered by the Ubuntu installer which is to install Ubuntu with grub as the bootloader. If Ubuntu boots OK after installing Ubuntu you are done, otherwise you have a default bootloader configuration that the Boot-Repair app understands as a starting point from which you can try to repair the boot problem.

Comment: I recommend against dual-boot systems with Windows. If something messes up, you are potentially locked out of two systems. Windows upgrades should also be strenuously avoided on dual boot systems.They like to think they are the only OS. If you need to share files, just use a memory stick or a large USB drive.